# Geoserver not recognizing jsonb attribute in SQL view of PostGIS db

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, sql, json

I have an instance of Geoserver 2.8.2 running and a PostGIS database. I am attempting to create a FeatureType based on an SQL view of the following table (viewed through psql \d):

```
                 Table "public.rapid_feature"
       Column       |          Type           | Modifiers
--------------------+-------------------------+-----------
 uid                | text                    | not null
 geom               | geometry(Geometry,4326) |
 bbox               | geometry(Polygon,4326)  |
 properties         | jsonb                   | not null
 create_timestamp   | time without time zone  |
 hash               | text                    |
 modified_timestamp | time without time zone  |
 layer_id           | text                    |
```

However, when I create an FeatureType based on an SQL View of this table, the `properties` attribute disappears:

[image]

Not sure what I need to do to make the `properties` column appear as an attribute in Geoserver.

Comment: You need to do a feature request. GeoServer does not support jsonb datatype. There are other not supported data types like HSTORE. As a workaround you could convert your field into TEXT.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for the info. Originally, I had the field as a JSON string, but I wasn't able to query with a CQL filter based on that string the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user30184 says to get a JSONB column to appear in GeoServer would involve adding the ability to read and understand them to the [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) [postgis datastore](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jdbc/postgis.html). The code for which is on [github](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/plugin/jdbc/jdbc-postgis/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/postgis).

As a quicker fix you could break that column out into it's component parts and store them as normal columns that GeoServer can recognise and that you could use CQL filters against.